# Import Version History from Microsoft Excel to SharePoint 2013 List Items PowersShell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, excel

I have all the **list items and Version History** in the **Excel file**.

I have added the items to the list with PowerShell.

Now I have to add version history to the list item with PowerShell.

How to achive this?

Comment: Add item with the data of the oldest version. Then update the same item with the newer data saving the item every time. In that way you will be able to replicate version history.

Comment: Actually I have to maintain teh Modified Time also, So how to add the modified time as per the CSV? is it possible? How?